# One or more reserved bits are on: reserved1 = 0, reserved2 = 1, reserved3 = 1

Tags: javascript, html, websocket, network-programming, phpwebsocket

In Chrome 50.0.2661.94 m

```
var a = new WebSocket('ws://192.168.0.153:9000/socket_listener_1_WINDOWS.php');
```

ERROR (from Yesterday afternoon- It works on the other clients pc's,  but also "ws://echo.websocket.org/" works using my pc as client)

```
WebSocket connection to 'ws://192.168.0.153:9000/socket_listener_1_WINDOWS.php' failed: One or more reserved bits are on: reserved1 = 0, reserved2 = 1, reserved3 = 1
```

(what and where are "reserved1, 2 and 3"???)

This is the PHP script of the server (launched with XAMPP 3.2.2):

```
<?php

//error_reporting(E_ALL);

set_time_limit(0);

$IP = isset($_SERVER['SERVER_ADDR']) ? $_SERVER['SERVER_ADDR'] : gethostbyname(gethostname());

echo $IP . '\r\n';

$host = $IP; //$_SERVER['SERVER_ADDR']; //host
$port = 9000; //port
$null = NULL;
$read = NULL;
$except = NULL;

function send_message($msg) {
    global $clients;
    foreach ($clients as $changed_socket) {
        @socket_write($changed_socket, $msg, strlen($msg));
    }
    return true;
}

//Unmask incoming framed message
function unmask($text) {
    $length = ord($text[1]) & 127;
    if ($length == 126) {
        $masks = substr($text, 4, 4);
        $data = substr($text, 8);
    } elseif ($length == 127) {
        $masks = substr($text, 10, 4);
        $data = substr($text, 14);
    } else {
        $masks = substr($text, 2, 4);
        $data = substr($text, 6);
    }
    $text = "";
    for ($i = 0; $i < strlen($data); ++$i) {
        $text .= $data[$i] ^ $masks[$i % 4];
    }
    return $text;
}

//Encode message for transfer to client.
function mask($text) {
    $b1 = 0x80 | (0x1 & 0x0f);
    $length = strlen($text);

    if ($length <= 125)
        $header = pack('CC', $b1, $length);
    elseif ($length > 125 && $length < 65536)
        $header = pack('CCn', $b1, 126, $length);
    elseif ($length >= 65536)
        $header = pack('CCNN', $b1, 127, $length);
    return $header . $text;
}

//handshake new client.
function perform_handshaking($receved_header, $client_conn, $host, $port) {
    $headers = array();
    $lines = preg_split("/\r\n/", $receved_header);
    foreach ($lines as $line) {
        $line = chop($line);
        if (preg_match('/\A(\S+): (.*)\z/', $line, $matches)) {
            $headers[$matches[1]] = $matches[2];
        }
    }

//var_dump($headers);

    $secKey = $headers['Sec-WebSocket-Key'];

    $secAccept = base64_encode(pack('H*', sha1($secKey . '258EAFA5-E914-47DA-95CA-C5AB0DC85B11')));
//hand shaking header
    $upgrade = "HTTP/1.1 101 Web Socket Protocol Handshake\r\n" .
            "Upgrade: websocket\r\n" .
            "Connection: Upgrade\r\n" .
            "WebSocket-Origin: $host\r\n" .
            "WebSocket-Location: ws://$host:$port/socket_listener_1.php\r\n" .
            "Sec-WebSocket-Accept:$secAccept\r\n\r\n";
    socket_write($client_conn, $upgrade, strlen($upgrade));
}

$ultimotimestamp = time();
//----------------------------------------------------------------------------------
//Così dovrebbe ripartire il socket in caso di crash
//Crea collegamento TCP/IP
$socket = socket_create(AF_INET, SOCK_STREAM, SOL_TCP);

//Se non ci si può connettere all'indirizzo del socket, quindi il server è chiuso
//riparte tutto se il server non si connette
/* -E- */ while (@socket_connect($socket, $host, $port) === FALSE) {

//Parte un nuovo server
    echo "SOCKET SERVER STARTED\n\n";

//Porta riutilizabile (DEFAULT SI)
    socket_set_option($socket, SOL_SOCKET, SO_REUSEADDR, 1);
//Crea collegamento TCP/IP
    $socket = socket_create(AF_INET, SOCK_STREAM, SOL_TCP);

//Lega il socket ad un indirizzo specifico
    if (socket_bind($socket, $host, $port) !== FALSE) {

//mette il socket server in ascolto
        socket_listen($socket);

//crea, e aggiunge il socket server alla lista
        $clients = array($socket);

//comincia un loop che non si ferma mai
        while (true) {


//la variabile changed prende la lista dei clienti (nel primo caso solo il server)
            $changed = $clients;

//La funzione socket_select() accetta un array di socket e si mette in attesa di una variazione di stato su questi. 
//Questa, derivando come background dai socket BSD, riconoscerà che questi array di risorse socket sono in realtà 
//dei set di descrittori di file. Saranno monitorati 3 set di socket.
            socket_select($changed, $read, $except, 10, 0);

//se in socket ci sono nuovi clients
            if (in_array($socket, $changed)) {

                $socket_new = socket_accept($socket); //accetta il nuovo socket (di default)

                $header = socket_read($socket_new, 2048); //legge l'header del nuovo client, al quale inviare i dati

                array_push($clients, $socket_new); //aggiunge alla lista dei clients il nuovo collegamento


                if (!empty($header)) { //Se l'header non è vuoto
                    perform_handshaking($header, $socket_new, $host, $port); //fa un nuovo handshake, ossia una sorta di codifica dei dati

                    socket_getpeername($socket_new, $ip); //prende l'ip dal socket connesso

                    $response = mask(json_encode(array('type' => 'system', 'message' => $ip . ' connected'))); //prepare json data
                    send_message($response); //notify all users about new connection

                    echo $ip . " connesso\n\n";
                }


                $found_socket = array_search($socket, $changed); //cerca array socket dentro changed

                unset($changed[$found_socket]); //elimina l'indice trovato dall'array
            }


            if (time() - $ultimotimestamp >= 5) {
                $response = mask(json_encode(array('type' => 'bip', 'message' => "1")));
                send_message($response); //notify all users about new connection

                $ultimotimestamp = time();
            }

//ciclo dei socket connessi
            foreach ($changed as $changed_socket) {

//scrive i dati del socket in un buffer di 2048 bytes
                /* -E- */ //while (socket_recv($changed_socket, $buf, 2048, 0) > 0) {
                while ($bytes = socket_recv($changed_socket, $buf, 2048, 0) > 1) {
//while (!false === ($buf = socket_read($changed_socket, 2048, PHP_BINARY_READ))) {
                    //var_dump($bytes);
//echo '\n\n';

                    $received_text = unmask($buf); //smaschera dati buffer
                    $tst_msg = json_decode($received_text); //decodifica in json 

                    $response_text = mask(json_encode($tst_msg)); //lo rimaschera
                    send_message($response_text); //invia il dato a $changed_socket, che è una risorsa socket

                    echo $response_text . "\n\n"; //Mostra il dato inviato a schermo

                    break 2; //esce fino al ciclo while (di 2 livelli sopra)
                }

//il buffer legge il socket di prima, fino a 2048 bytes
                /* -E- */ //if (socket_recv($changed_socket, $buf, 2048, 0) === FALSE) { // se il $buf è false, quindi si presuppone che il client sia disconnesso

                if ($bytes = socket_recv($changed_socket, $buf, 2048, 0) === FALSE) {
                    var_dump($bytes);
                    $found_socket = array_search($changed_socket, $clients);
                    socket_getpeername($changed_socket, $ip);
                    unset($clients[$found_socket]); // rimuove il client dall'array dei clients
                }
            }
            //sleep(0.05);
        }
        socket_close($socket); //in caso di errore del ciclo si chiude il socket in ascolto
    }
    socket_close($socket);
}
socket_close($socket);
```

SERVER SCREEN:
[image: socket listener]

CLIENT SCREEN
[image: opcode]

[image: response header]

This is the Wireshark TCP trace from my client. Ask me if you need new screenshots.

[image: tcp trace]

I have no Firewalls and Antivirus activated. Do you know why it doesn't work on my pc? It worked for 1 year first.

Thank you

Answer (score 0):

In my experience, even [RFC6455](https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc6455) didn't remarks RSV1, but I have tested it is representing "isMasked" on Chrome.

Comment: Do you think what I could do to fix?

Comment: Have you comment out all echo before you test? I just succeed with your PHP script after removed echo.

Comment: I just tried, but always "WebSocket connection to 'ws://192.168.0.153:9000/socket_listener_1_WINDOWS.php' failed: One or more reserved bits are on: reserved1 = 0, reserved2 = 1, reserved3 = 1"

Comment: try this>var a = new WebSocket('ws://192.168.0.153:9000/')

Comment: now i'm trying with another client computer. let's look

Comment: Ok, I'm using the same server, and Ubuntu14.04 on elementary OS 0.3.2 64 bit, with Chromium 48.0.2564.116 like client, and it's working. May be a Chrome bug (with the updates)?

Comment: I cannot reproduce the fail case. I think you have to step in to network level to monitor what data exactly received, Wireshark is quite friendly with WebSocket.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/111200/discussion-between-davide-caballeros-and-shintiger).